# Laravel: SQLSTATE HY000 2002 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to migrate migrations to MySQL database using `php artisan migrate` in Laravel 5.2's Homestead on my local machine. I keep getting this error:

```
[PDOException]

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it.
```

I can connect to the database just fine using MySQL workbench, but I want to use laravel's migration feature.

My `database.php` looks like this:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.10.10'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laraveldb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Check these two: `'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),`. Are those the `username` and `password` of database ?

Comment: is your apache and mysql running ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use these default settings in your .env file:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Also, be sure `homestead` database is created.

The thing is `.env` settings override `database.php` ones.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#connecting-to-databases)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that file existed. Laravel Homestead manual doesn't say much* about it. It is in the Laravel installation folder and because it has a weird extension, Sublime text editor doesn't see it. In your answer, I also replaced `DB_DATABASE=laraveldb` to match my database name in `database.php`

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I've also added link to a Homestead documentation, maybe this info will help you too (info such as the standard Homestead ports, `.env` related info etc).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on xampp then you can try it again. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Tried using different ports IPs?

127.0.0.1 33060

192.168.10.10 3306 or 33060 nd its working

Homestead v12